# Add a loop until user inputs a valid answer?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I want to add a loop to this:

```
question = raw_input("Reboot Y/N ")
if len(question) > 0 and question.isalpha():
    answer = question.upper()
    if answer == "Y":
        print "Reboot"
    elif answer == "N":
        print "Reboot Cancled"
    else:
        print "/ERROR/"
```

So if the user inputs anything else the error appears and sends them back to the question.

Comment: You realize that if the user types anything other than a letter, he's not going to get any response at all, right? Is that what you intended?

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted and closed? This seems like a common beginner question.

Comment: Canonical duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 6):

Add a while True at the top, and if user has entered correct output, break the loop: -

```
while True:
    question = raw_input("Reboot Y/N ")
    if len(question) > 0:
        answer = question.upper()
        if answer == "Y":
            print "Reboot"
            break
        elif answer == "N":
            print "Reboot Canceled"
            break
        else:
            print "/ERROR/"
```

Comment: Might want to remove that `and question.isalpha()` part, too.

Comment: @martineau.. Yeah that was in fact not needed. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the response, I'm a novice coder and new to the site so sorry for the very bad question :'(

Comment: @Molly.. You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
answer={"Y":"Reboot","N":"Reboot cancled"} #use a dictionary instead of if-else
inp=raw_input("Reboot Y/N: ")

while inp not in ('n','N','y','Y') :  #use a tuple to specify valid inputs
   print "invalid input"
   inp=raw_input("Reboot Y/N: ")

print answer[inp.upper()]
```

**output:**

```
$ python so27.py

Reboot Y/N: foo
invalid input
Reboot Y/N: bar
invalid input
Reboot Y/N: y
Reboot
```